# Creating a MySQL database from a .sql file

Tags: mysql, database

Though a very similar question has been asked ([How to convert .sql file to tables in mysql db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394058/how-to-convert-sql-file-to-tables-in-mysql-db)), my limited experience (read almost zero) of MySQL server means that that particular answer does not help me.

I have followed the steps from the first answer:

1.Create empty database for which I found the following command:

```
mysqladmin create myDBname
```

When I check `/var/lib/mysql` I can see the folder myDBname with a placeholder db.opt file inside.

2.Read in the .sql file like so:

```
mysql -u root -p myDBname < dotSQLfile.sql
```

However, this doesn't appear to do *anything*.  Should I expect the myDBname to be populated in some sense in the `/var/lib/mysql/myDBname` directory?

When I run `mysqlshow` it only lists 'information_schema' & 'test' as databases...?  Yet if I manually run MySQL and source the .sql file, I can see the database within that environment and run queries:

```
mysql -u root -p

source dotSQLfile.sql;
show tables;
select * from table1;
```

but as soon as I quit mysql, it's no longer visible.  Am I doing something wrong?

I should add I'm using MariaDB on Fedora19; mysqld is running.

Comment: Can you post the structure of your first table in dotSQLfile.sql?

Comment: Apologies for the horrible formatting...

| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          
| code             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| name             | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title            | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| owner            | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |

Comment: @user2723429 The create and import commands seem ok. Are you sure of the dotSQLfile.sql location and that it is a valid sql file? Also are you running mysqlshow as 'root'? If not, perhaps that is why you can't see myDBname.

Comment: also, in general I think you shouldn't be looking at the folder structure, rather inspect your databases through the mysql line or a client, such as MySQL Workbench

Comment: @ile thanks.  If I run msqlshow as root I can see the DB (thanks btw!), but if I inspect the database on the command line via mysql, it's an empty DB, show tables returns an empty set.  It's simply not populating the DB.  Also, pretty sure it's a valid sql file since, as above, I can 'source' it on the mysql command line and inspect the DB and run queries as expected.

Comment: @user2723429 could you upload a link to your sql file for inspection (if it is not confidential)? Also, just to double check, you do select (**'use'** command) the database before running 'show tables;' right?

Comment: You can use clients like SQLyog or Navicat.