# How to convert .sql file to .db file for sqlite use in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have searched alot but not found any proper solution.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to rename it... but seriously, what you expect to get as an answer?

Answer (score -2):

**Using mysql:**

```
 mysql -u root -p databaseName < file.sql
```

Where databaseName is an already created empty database and file.sql is the .sql file you have, you must be in the same folder as the file when you run the command. This also assumes using root as the user and that it is password protected. Modify as needed for your own setup.

Additionally, you can do the reverse by flipping the angled bracket to create a database dump to a file. Like below.

```
mysql -u root -p databaseName > file.sql
```

The answer is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394058/how-to-convert-sql-file-to-tables-in-mysql-db).